# Set Position of Floating Action Button [in Floating Action Menu]

Tags: android, floating-action-button

Is there any one experience on setting position of floating action button [FAB] that put in floating action menu [FAM]?

Due to the screen size doesn't fit the amount of FAB [14], so I need few FABs on second column/ other position.
[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW63z.jpg)

This is my case:
final com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu famLeft = (com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu) findViewById(R.id.menu_labels_left);

for (int i = 13; i >= 0; i--) {

```
com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton fabLeft = new com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton(this);

String uri = "@drawable/" + hr_logo[i];

int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());

Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageResource);

bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, dpToPx(40), dpToPx(40), true);

fabLeft.setImageBitmap(bm);

fabLeft.setLabelText(sub_cat_name[i]);

fabLeft.setColorNormal(R.color.WetAsphalt);

famLeft.addMenuButton(fabLeft);

fabLeft.setButtonSize(FloatingActionButton.SIZE_MINI);

fabLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
    }

});
```

}

Comment: You haven't provided any relevant code or attempts to achieve this. We can' help like this.

Answer (score 0):

Do check this library on github

https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton

you might get a solution here. or simply a work around may be.

or rather I will suggest you to position your FABs in xml wherever you want. and handle the visibility of each of the FAB from your program.

and may be you should go for scrolling FABs in a single column, I am not sure how to develop this one, I think that would be the best approach though.

**Happy Coding!**

Comment: I found that source before before. I'm able to create few FABs but there is a limitation for fitting 14 FABs. I want it in 2 columns as the image shown above. or how am I going to set the position of single FAB but not FAM.

Comment: I think it wouldn't be in xml as those FABs are loaded dynamically. Ya, I wonder is there scrolling FABs. BTW, thanks of your suggestions.

Comment: and actually I have tried "setX" and "setY", the positions are able to be set but the labels of FABs are not placed right besides FAB.